# Default Compute Engine service account cant access Cloud SQL

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

Im trying to get my compute engine instance to communicate with Cloud SQL using the Proxy. I keep getting this error when I try to start the proxy:

> the default Compute Engine service account is not configured with
>   sufficient permissions to access the Cloud SQL API from this VM. 
>   Please create a new VM with Cloud SQL access (scope) enabled under
>   "Identity and API access".  Alternatively, create a new "service
>   account key" and specify it using the -credentials_file parameter

When I describe my instance using `gcloud compute instances describe` the service account and scopes are:

```
serviceAccounts:
- email: 123456-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  scopes:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin
```

I can get this working if I create a new instance with full scope permissions:

```
serviceAccounts:
- email: 123456-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  scopes:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

But this seems less secure than just specifying the scopes I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue fixed in https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/pull/21.

We will roll out a new release on Monday (4/18). Or you can compile from the source on github. Sorry for the inconvenience.